# Enumerate outgoing RDP sessions?

Tags: windows, winapi, rdp

Let's say I open an RPD session to `Server 1` and another RPD session to `Server 2` on my local computer. I would like to query the information of these two RDP sessions open from my computer.

I tried the following options:

- WTS APIs: WTSEnumerateSessions
- qwinsta

All these methods return information about sessions open "to" the computer, but I need information about sessions open "from" computer.

Does anyone know of a way to return this info?

Comment: My local machine connect to a external Virtual Machine via Remote Desktop, I can enum this seesion when running the application as administrator. Can you show how do you call `WTSEnumerateSessions` API?

Comment: I used this code: https://gist.github.com/tanaka-takayoshi/7daadf6c2ea0fd2434b3 for C#. Tried running the application as Administrator also, but it did not help. Do you run your app on local machine or external VM?

Comment: On local machine.